# What does it mean for one's soul to "be like dust to everyone"?

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, soul

From the end of the Amidah: *"To those who curse me, let my soul be silent; and let my soul be like dust to everyone"*. What does it mean, for one's soul to be like dust? And why is it a good thing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Most undertand this to be a prayer for the trait of humility; specifically as expressed by ignoring the abuse of others.

This is implied by the  [Chovos Halevavos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chovot_HaLevavot) (Shaar Hac'nia ch. 10):

> והששי כי מעשה הנכנע מקובל אצל האלקים...וחשוב בו תמיד והשתדל לקנותו ופקדהו עם נפשך ומדותיך תדיר והעזר באלקים עליו ושאל אותו ממנו להתקרב אליו ולהגיע לרצונו אולי יישירך לו ויכין לך הדרך אליו כמו שמתפללים החסידים אחר תפלתם אלהי נצור לשוני מרע ושפתי מדבר מרמה ולמקללי נפשי תדום ונפשי כעפר לכל תהיה, והזהר מהרהור לבך ופתויי היצר לך במה שיביאך אליו מהגובה והגאוה והגאון ובקשת השררה והגדולה והממשלה.

And [Ra'avan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_ben_Nathan) (12th cent. Germany) [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_21968_166.pdf#xml=http://www.hebrewbooks.org/hilite.aspx?pgnum=166&hilite=b531c201-5b1b-478d-a0bb-998883637ddb&toolbar=1&navpanes=0&statusbar=0&view=FitH) (cited [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_43535_402.pdf#xml=http://www.hebrewbooks.org/hilite.aspx?pgnum=402&hilite=937b0969-8b6c-4a79-8fe6-26960c2a205e&toolbar=1&navpanes=0&statusbar=0&view=FitH)). (Note that it is missatributed to R. Shelomo of Germiza).

[Adudirham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Abudirham) (ch. 18) too implies that this refers to the trait of humility (like the Chovos Halevavos). Just as the Earth humbly bears all who trod on it, so too, one should humble himself. Abudirham adds the twist that dirt is ultimately needed by the inhabitants of the Earth, and so too, one who humbles himself, will occupy a prominent position in the World to Come.

> להיות כעפר לפני הכל והטעם לרמוז בו שהעפר הכל רומסים אותו ברגליהם ועולה על ראשיהם וגם לסוף הכל צריכים לו, כך המשפיל עצמו בעוה"ז יהיה לראש לעוה"ב

Similarly, [R. Ezriel Dienna](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%93%D7%90%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%94) (15th-16th cent. Italy) [cites](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_21341_275.pdf#xml=http://www.hebrewbooks.org/hilite.aspx?pgnum=275&hilite=f0c04356-0dc9-4476-823d-5c18a518c79d&toolbar=1&navpanes=0&statusbar=0&view=FitH) an example of the trait being prayed for in Mar Zutra who every night, wold forgive all who had harmed him. Evidently, like Chovos Halevavos, et al.he understood that this refers to the trait of humbly accepting the abuse of others.

The [Sefer Charedim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elazar_ben_Moshe_Azikri) (Laws Dependent on the Land: ch. 5), [Shelah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaiah_Horowitz) (Yoma) and P'nei David (Chayei Sarah) write in a similar vein as well.

- However, as noted by @fred Tosafos in B'rachos 17a explain it as referring to the eternal nature nature of the Earth. One prays that ones progeny never be destroyed.

> מה עפר אינו מקבל כליה לעולם כן יהי רצון שזרעי לא יכלה לעולם

- See [Netziv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naftali_Zvi_Yehuda_Berlin) ([Meromei Sadeh to B'rachos 17a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40994&st=&pgnum=24&hilite=)) for a kabbalistic explanation.

Comment: Thank you for all this. I particularly like "the trait of humbly accepting the abuse of others", as that helps join the more general second half of the sentence to the first half, which I had had no problem understanding. (My thinking had gone down a couple of thoroughly confusing blind alleys)

Answer (score 9):

One interpretation is that given by Tosafos ([*B'rachos* 17a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=17&format=text), s.v. ונפשי כעפר):

> ונפשי כעפר לכל תהיה. מה עפר אינו מקבל כליה לעולם כן יהי רצון שזרעי לא יכלה לעולם כמו שהוא אומר והיה זרעך כעפר הארץ

Translation:

> "And may my soul be like dirt/dust to all": Just as the dirt can never be destroyed, so may it be Your will that my progeny is never destroyed, as the verse says, "And your seed shall be like the dust of the earth" ([*B'reishis* 28:14](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0128.htm#14)).